# shell script for d in */ ; do is running locally, but it's not working in circleci

Tags: shell, sh, circleci

I built a script and when i try to run it locally it works fine, but when I run that on circleci I'm getting an error.

This is the script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for d in */ ; do
    cd $d
    for f in * ; do
        if [[ $f == *.sh ]]; then    
            if [[ $d == "test/" ]]; then
                echo "$d"
            else
                bash *.sh
            fi
        else
            if [[ $f == *.yaml ]]; then  
                echo "$file"
            fi
        fi
    done
    cd ..
done
```

And this is the error that I got on ci

```
generate-docs.sh: 4: cd: can't cd to */
generate-docs.sh: 6: [[: not found
generate-docs.sh: 15: [[: not found
```

Comment: First error: there are no directories in the current directory. When that happens, by default, the glob pattern is simply turned into a string.

Comment: Other errors: the script is not being run with bash, but with plain sh instead.

Comment: Also ,`bash *.sh` -- what do you think that does?

Comment: @glennjackman I actually wasn't running the script with bash, so I could fix the first and second error, but about  "bash *.sh". I  running that to try to compile all scripts inside the directory $d, but it's not working. Do you know the correct way to do that?

Comment: @glennjackman I just did that but the loop keeps infinity

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the line

```sh
bash *.sh
```

You seem to want to run all scripts at once. Assuming the shell files are "a.sh", "b.sh", "c.sh" etc, then the shell expands that into `bash a.sh b.sh c.sh ...` meaning the first one (alphabetically) is run with all the others given as arguments. You need to loop, executing one at a time. But you're already inside a loop, so what you need there is

```sh
bash "$f"
```

Answer (score 0):

(I don't know *circleci*, but my suggestion is too lengthy to go into a comment, so I write it as answer):

First of all, I would veriry that the script runs in the correct location and using the correct shell. Therefore, I would put at the start of your script a guard like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if test -z "${BASH_VERSION}"
then
  echo "Needs to be executed with bash!"
  exit 1
fi
echo Working Directory is "$PWD"
set -x # Only for debugging. Remove it when everything works
# ... your remaining script goes here
```